# Router as Access Point + Repeater

Tags: wifi, repeater, router, lte

Is there a way to use a wireless router as some sort of Access Point + Repeater?
I have a LTE Box with a SIM Card that has a build-in router which is pretty shitty.

I now want to connect a proper router to this LTE Box (via WIFI, since the LTE Box has no LAN Port) to get internet access and then connect only to the router (via LAN Port, since I don't trust in WIFI).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your W-Lan Router. 
Some devices got a function called WDS -> Wifi Distributed Service. 
You need to specify the signal and the login data for the wlan router who should distribute the original signal.